# How to change order of columns while exporting CSV data in Datatables?

Tags: php, csv, datatables

I have TableTools file version like below

File:        TableTools.min.js
Version:     2.1.4

I have a scenario like below

1. I have a data-table with Export to Excel / CSV (from client side)
2. In data table I need columns in the order 0,1,2,3,4 and so on
3. While exporting into excel I need columns in the order 0,2,1,4,3.

Is that possible in Table Tools? If so could you please help me.

**Edit**
I have following code:

```
"oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "path/to/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": [
        {
            "sExtends":    "collection",
            "sButtonText": "Export",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sFileName": "Sample.csv",
                    "oSelectorOpts": {
                            page: 'current'
                    },
                    "mColumns": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
                    "fnClick": function (nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
                        //$(".DTTT_button_xls").trigger('click');
                        oTable.colReorder.order( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15 ] );
                    }
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sFileName": "Sample.xls",
                    "oSelectorOpts": {
                        page: 'current'
                    },
                    "mColumns": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: `mColumns: [ 0,2,1,4,3 ]` is the correct approach, but it only works along with `sExtends`, (as far as I recall) - you should seriously consider the buttons plugin instead, it does the same - much easier, and is maintained and more crossbrowser-friendly.  Your `oTableTools` struct seems a little bit odd, try with only _one_ button and _no_ collection. Dont know who have downvoted, people should leave an explanation why they downvoted (to my opinion, when the question as in this case is fair and square and well written even with code example) have adjusted the balance a bit :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, You are right. I tried you said above but even with Single `sExtends` it's not working.

Comment: Try the latest and final 2,2,4 version -> https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools I really cant tell. It is years since I used tabletools, but can see in old code I have done the same as you) what dataTables version are you using? You should use at least 1.9.2, I would say - it is not sure tabletools work with a 1.10.x `DataTable()` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any existing feature available in Datatables that can re-order columns while exporting them.

So I had to write a `PHP` code at server side and had generate `CSV' file from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ExportButton").on("Click", function (e) {
    table.colReorder.order( [ 0,2,1,4,3 ] );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but how to write this as could not found the place.

Comment: 1. Find the variable name of your table and replace "table". If none - replace with $("TableID").
2. Find the ID on your export button and replace with "ExportButton".
3. Place my code inside $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); after your DataTables initialization.

Comment: Oh my mistake I read TableTools as DataTables. This would be a alternative work around then.

Comment: Does this problem have any solution from official library itself ?, after two years.